# get os.walk hit abspath

Tags: python, os.walk, os.path

I'm trying to find several `'my_file.bat'` with `os.walk()`, in a `foldersystem`, if the filename matches it should be called with `subprocess.call()` or `.run()`. The problem is that the `os.path.abspath('my_file.bat')` gives back a joint `'where\i\ran\the\script\from' + ˇmy_file.batˇ`.
Could anyone tell me why is this happening and how could I get the `'my_file.bat'` location?

```
import os
import subprocess

for root, dir, name in os.walk(r'C:\the\path\i\am\using\for\the\folder\system'):
    for filename in name:
        if filename == 'my_file.bat':
            my_file_path = os.path.abspath('my_file.bat')
            os.chdir(my_file_path)
            subprocess.call('my_file.bat')
```

Answer (score 2):

`abspath` isn't going to help you since it computes the path *from current directory*. How can `abspath` be aware of what `walk` is doing ?

Besides `os.chdir(my_file_path)` tries to change the directory with a *file* as argument... Well, better not use `chdir` in a python script, *ever*.

> how could I get the 'my_file.bat' location?

You don't need that (and it won't suffice to execute the file). What you want is to execute the file with the current directory set to the directory of the script (making the .bat file simpler)

The `root` variable, on the other hand, provides the directory where the file is located. So I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
for root, dir, name in os.walk(r'C:\the\path\i\am\using\for\the\folder\system'):
    for filename in name:
        if filename.lower() == 'my_file.bat':
            subprocess.call('my_file.bat',shell=True,cwd=root)
```

Adding `cwd=root` allows `call` to change directory to the script directory prior to execution (and only in the call), where `shell=True` (your next problem) ensures that you can call a script (not a real executable) from `subprocess.call`

Also use lowercase comparison in case the file is called `MY_FILE.BAT`. You have to love windows for all those quirks.

Answer (score 2):

Better use `pathlib`, which makes the for-loop much easier:

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess

root = Path(r'C:\the\path\i\am\using\for\the\folder\system')
for filename in root.rglob('my_file.bat')
    subprocess.call(filename.name, cwd=filename.parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the path of the file that you got through `os.walk`, use `os.path.join` to join the `root` and the `filename`:

```
my_file_path = os.path.join(root, 'my_file.bat')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the path to your file by using:

```
my_file_path = root+"\\"+filename
```

The reason you are getting the wrong location is because python returns the current folder location with name when using `os.path.abspath()`

Answer (score 0):

so my solution took some time, but this worked for me:

batchFileFullPath = os.path.join(batchFileLocation, 'my_bat_file.bat')

p = subprocess.Popen(os.path.abspath(batchFileFullPath), stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     cwd=batchFileLocation)stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

To be honest I have no idea why it works, but it does.
Thanks for your ideas. :)